# В каком стандарте Си разрешили обьявлять переменные в любом месте функции?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

В каком стандарте Си разрешили объявлять переменные в любом месте функции?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В любом месте - начиная с С99.

Не совсем понятна, правда, привязка к *функции*. В классическом ANSI C (C89/90) тоже можно было делать локальные объявления "в любом месте функции", если это "место" являлось началом *блока*. Такая возможность появилась еще в достандартные времена - она присутствует уже в первом издании K&R C. Начиная же с С99 разрешается делать локальные объявления в любом месте *блока*.

Требование выноса локальных объявлений в начало именно *функции* существовало только уж в совсем архаичных версиях языка, типа описанной в [C Reference Manual](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf).